# How to run my installed rpm package?

Tags: linux, rpm

I have a package that I've installed using

```
sudo rpm -i getlisteners-debuginfo-1.0.0-113.el7.x86_64
```

How do I then run my package?

The non-debug version can be run using "getlisteners" in terminal:

```
sudo rpm -i getlisteners-1.0.0-113.el7.x86_64
getlisteners
```

I want to run the debug version but getlisteners-debuginfo doesn't work. How do I know the keyword to run the program I've just installed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would be helpful if you write what this getlisteners package is and any reference to it online

Comment: It is a package developed and released internally, so there isn't any reference online. I was wondering if there's a general way to tell how to run a program installed by an rpm.

Answer (score 0):

A package can be installed anywhere. Try to run the following to see where the files where installed to:

```
sudo rpm -ql getlisteners-debuginfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Debuginfo package is not what you think is.

You can read about it here https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Debuginfo/

> debuginfo package contains stripped symbols from ELF binaries (*.debug in /usr/lib/debug) as well as the source code related to them (in /usr/src/debug).

The package `getlisteners` contains what you need. The list of executables can be obtained e.g. (I used `bash` because I do not have `getlisteners` installed:

```
$ rpm -ql bash |grep /bin/
/usr/bin/alias
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bashbug
/usr/bin/bashbug-64
/usr/bin/bg
/usr/bin/cd
/usr/bin/command
/usr/bin/fc
/usr/bin/fg
/usr/bin/getopts
/usr/bin/hash
/usr/bin/jobs
/usr/bin/read
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/type
/usr/bin/ulimit
/usr/bin/umask
/usr/bin/unalias
/usr/bin/wait
```

If it happens that your program crash (coredumped) and you want to debug it, you get something like:

Backtrace was generated from '/usr/bin/epiphany'

```
(no debugging symbols found)
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
(no debugging symbols found)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread -1241265952 (LWP 12630)]
(no debugging symbols found)
0xb7f25410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#0  0xb7f25410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb741b45b in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
[...]
```

This is not useful at all. Neither for you nor for the developer of the program. To get a useful backtrace, you have to install the corresponding debuginfo. With precisely the same version and release. Then the backtrace will looks like:

```
thread 1 (LWP 186031):
#0  0x00007f03095769fe in gtk_window_set_title (window=0xdeadbeaf, title=title@entry=0x5653af368bc0 "xsettingsd killed by SIGABRT - org.freedesktop.GnomeAbrt") at ../gtk/gtkwindow.c:2415
        __inst = 0xdeadbeaf
        __t = <optimized out>
        __r = <optimized out>
        _g_boolean_var_21 = <optimized out>
        __func__ = "gtk_window_set_title"
#1  0x00005653adcbe381 in update_window_title () at /usr/src/debug/libreport-2.17.9-1.fc38.x86_64/src/gui-wizard-gtk/wizard.c:333
        prgname = <optimized out>
        reason = <optimized out>
        title = 0x5653af368bc0 "xsettingsd killed by SIGABRT - org.freedesktop.GnomeAbrt"
#2  0x00005653adcc0dc7 in update_gui_state_from_problem_data (flags=0) at /usr/src/debug/libreport-2.17.9-1.fc38.x86_64/src/gui-wizard-gtk/wizard.c:1115
        reason = <optimized out>
        not_reportable = <optimized out>
        t = <optimized out>
        stats = {filesize = 94917423599536, filecount = 2943322400}
        msg = <optimized out>
        reproducible = <optimized out>
        count_str = <optimized out>
        __func__ = <optimized out>
```

This is useful. You get this output by calling the same executable as before. The debuginfo is only needed when you analyze the dumped core and you produce the backtrace for humans.

More information about the retrieval of backtraces: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Debugging/Getting_traces

The `*-debuginfo` does not contain any executable. Never. They only contain the debugging symbols and the referenced source code. Nothing else.